# Lua getting parameter from Nodejs

Tags: node.js, lua, redis

I'd like to ask that how could it be possible to send a data from Nodejs to Lua script so that I can use that parameter to eliminate redis data result and a faster search processes.Here is my code

**Lua script**

```
-- parameter data should be taken here
local ks=redis.call('ZRANGE', 'mykey', '0', '-1')
return (ks)
```

**NodeJS**

```
const Redis = require("redis");
const config = require("../resource/config");
const fs = require("fs");

const redis = Redis.createClient({
  port: config.redis.port,
  host: config.redis.host,
  db: config.redis.index
});

let script = fs.readFileSync("./file.lua");
redis.eval(script, 0, [], "some how sending parameter here ", (err, resp)       => {
   console.log(resp);
   redis.quit();
});
```

Thank you Best Regards.

Answer (score 3):

After researching and trying a lot, I figured out that

```
redis.eval(script, 0, ["parameter1"],["parameter2"], (err, resp)       => {
   console.log(resp);
   redis.quit();
});
```

and to take parameter at lua script is

```
    return ARGV[1] --parameter1
    return ARGV[2] --parameter2
```